# How to combine two actions together

Tags: zapier

I have two API calls, one is an input for the second, I'm defining them as two actions now, but I wonder if I can merge them together in one action, I couldn't find that in the documentation, is that possible? and how?
My case is that I have an action that creates an invoice and returns back its id, the id then is being passed to another API to confirm that invoice and returns back a pdf.

Should I encapsulate the APIs from the back-end? or does it work if I called the second API inside the "then" method:

```
const options = {
  url: 'https://my.fastbill.com/api/1.0/api.php',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json'
  },
  params: {

  },
  body: {
    'SERVICE': 'invoice.complete',
    'DATA' : {    
      'INVOICE_ID': bundle.inputData.INVOICE_ID
    }
  }
}

return z.request(options)
  .then((response) => {
    response.throwForStatus();
    const results = response.json;

    // Call the second API here

    return results;
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use a hidden trigger to call the first action and pass the input into a dynamic dropdown , then use it along the other inputs to submit the final action.

https://platform.zapier.com/cli_tutorials/dynamic-dropdowns

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).